# How do I coerce a tibble dataframe column from double to time?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm in the tidyverse.

I read in several CSV files using `read_csv` (all have the same columns)

```
df <- read_csv("data.csv")
```

to obtain the a series of dataframes. After a bunch of data cleaning and calculations, I want to merge all the dataframes.

There are a dozen dataframes of several hundred rows, and a few dozen columns. A minimal example is

```
DF1
ID             name   costcentre start  stop  date
  <chr>          <chr>  <chr>      <time> <tim> <chr>    
1 R_3PMr4GblKPV~ Geo    Prizm      01:00  03:00 25/12/2019 
2 R_s6IDep6ZLpY~ Chevy  Malibu        NA     NA NA       
3 R_238DgbfO0hI~ Toyota Corolla    08:00  11:00 25/12/2019 


DF2
ID                  name   costcentre start stop   date
<chr>               <chr>  <chr>      <lgl> <time> <chr>
1 R_3PMr4GblKPV1OYd Geo    Prizm      NA       NA  NA   
2 R_s6IDep6ZLpYvUeR Chevy  Malibu     NA    03:00  12/12/2019
3 R_238DgbfO0hItPxZ Toyota Corolla    NA       NA  NA
```

Based on my cleaning requirements (is start == NA & stop != NA), some of the NAs in `start` must be `00:00`. I can enter a zero in that cell:

```
df <- within(df, start[is.na(df$start) & !is.na(df$stop)] <- 0)
```

This results in

```
DF1
ID             name   costcentre start  stop  date
  <chr>          <chr>  <chr>      <time> <tim> <chr>    
1 R_3PMr4GblKPV~ Geo    Prizm      01:00  03:00 25/12/2019 
2 R_s6IDep6ZLpY~ Chevy  Malibu        NA     NA NA       
3 R_238DgbfO0hI~ Toyota Corolla    08:00  11:00 25/12/2019 


DF2
ID                  name   costcentre start stop   date
<chr>               <chr>  <chr>      <dbl> <time> <chr>
1 R_3PMr4GblKPV1OYd Geo    Prizm      NA       NA  NA   
2 R_s6IDep6ZLpYvUeR Chevy  Malibu       0   03:00  12/12/2019
3 R_238DgbfO0hItPxZ Toyota Corolla    NA       NA  NA
```

I run into issues on merging, as sometimes `start` is a double (as I've done some replacements), is logical (as there were all NAs with no replacements), or is time (if there were some times in the original data reading)

```
merged_df <- bind_rows(DF1, DF2,...)
```

gives me the error `Error: Column`start`can't be converted from hms, difftime to numeric`

How do I coerce the start column to be of the type `time` so that I may merge my data?

Comment: You haven't shared a reproducible example to test this but try `within(df, start[is.na(df$start) & !is.na(df$stop)] <- as.POSIXct(NA))`

Comment: @RonakShah I don't want to add an NA. I want to add a "00:00" and make the entire start column be of type "time".

Comment: What sort of `time` object to you have or want? From which package? Are you using the `hms` package, as the error message suggests?

Comment: I am not sure how you got column with `"Time"` class. Can you share data with `dput`  ? Your post is still not reproducible, you can read here to know how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I just added a reproducible example to the original question and adjusted the title (to clarify that the time column is actually a time object of the hms package). But for some reason the adjustment was rejected in the review by @kkuilla. Still,  there is a reproducible example below in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the important point is that the columns **start** and **stop**, which appear to be of type **time**, are based on the **hms** package. I wondered why/when  is displayed, becauses I had not heared about this class before.

As I see it, these columns are actually of class **hms** and **difftime**. Such objects are actually stored not in minutes (as the printed tibble suggests) but in seconds. We see this if we look at the data via `View(df)`. Interestingly, if we print the data, the variable type is displayed as **time**.

To solve your problem, you have to convert all your start and stop columns consistently into hms difftime columns as in the example below.

**Minimal reproducible example:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(hms)

df1 <- tibble(id = 1:3, 
              start = as_hms(as.difftime(c(1*60,NA,8*60), units = "mins")),
              stop = as_hms(as.difftime(c(3*60,NA,11*60), units = "mins")))
df2 <- tibble(id = 4:6, 
              start = c(NA,NA,NA), 
              stop = as_hms(as.difftime(c(NA,3*60,NA), units = "mins")))
```

**Or even easier (but with slightly different printing than in the question):**

```
df1 <- tibble(id = 1:3, 
              start = as_hms(c(1*60,NA,8*60)),
              stop = as_hms(c(3*60,NA,11*60)))
df2 <- tibble(id = 4:6, 
              start = c(NA,NA,NA), 
              stop = as_hms(c(NA,3*60,NA)))
```

**Solving the problem:**

```
class(df1$start) # In df1 start has class hms and difftime
class(df2$start) # In df2 start has class logical

# We set start=0 if stop is not missing and turn the whole column into an hms object
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(start = new_hms(ifelse(!is.na(stop), 0, NA)))

# Now that column types are consistent across tibbles we can easily bind them together
df <- bind_rows(df1, df2)
df
```

Comment: I'm not currently able to test your solution but the type time occurs by itself upon reading on the data. The original is a string such as "03:15:00". Because it happened by itself, I didn't really know where to begin.

Comment: I just included an even simpler reproducible example. If it still does not work, maybe you need to start a new session (Session > Restart R). It is a fully reproducible example and works in a fresh session.

Comment: That does work. I think that the key is the mutate. That sets the entire column, rather than individual elements within it.